# Combining HTML CSS with Rmarkdown

Tags: html, css, r, r-markdown

On my way to becoming a datajournalist, I have come across lots of fantastic tools, such as R and Rmarkdown. Now that I work for a proper newspaper, I realize that most of the time, I end up using MS Excel (which, I don't deny, is also a great tool) and a concatenate function that I paste in an HTML file. I am losing quite a lot of my R knowledge and practice, and that's sad.

I know that I will soon be faced with a task that I would like to use as a way to get back to R and Rmarkdown.

I have some html pages working just fine and I'd like to change the data that is presented in them using Rmd.

My question is : is there a package or a way to combine into one Rmarkdown file most of an HTML page (header, css and javascript files and analytics, footer), and some Rmarkdown chunks ?

Thanks a lot for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try something like this (http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html#includes):

```
---
title: "Habits"
output:
  html_document:
    includes:
      in_header: header.html
      before_body: doc_prefix.html
      after_body: doc_suffix.html
---
```

This would allow the combination of html and Rmd in general. Furthermore there is the chunk option `child`, which would allow to use Rmd files as chunk content?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **.css** files to style your Rmakdown. In the header you do something like:

```
---
title: "Habits"
output:
html_document:
  css: styles.css
---
```

see [this](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html#appearance-and-style)